# CreateProcessAsUser function to run a GUI program from a service

Tags: java, windows-services, jna, interactive

Below is the code I am using to run a GUI app from service application. I am passing cmd string "C:\Windows\notepad.exe".

It is not opening the Notepad and not even giving any error. hToken is null even after using WTSQueryUserToken.
Here is a documentation link for create process as user : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessasusera

```
private void cpasUser(String cmd) {
        HANDLE h = null; 
        final HANDLEByReference childStdInRead = new HANDLEByReference();
        final HANDLEByReference childStdInWrite = new HANDLEByReference();
        final HANDLEByReference childStdOutRead = new HANDLEByReference();
        final HANDLEByReference childStdOutWrite = new HANDLEByReference();
        
        final int HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT = 0x00000001;
        final int HANDLE_FLAG_PROTECT_FROM_CLOSE = 0x00000002;
        
        final int BUFSIZE = 4096;
        final int GENERIC_READ = 0x80000000;
        final int FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY = 1;
        final int OPEN_EXISTING = 3;
        final DWORD STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE = new DWORD(-11);
        final int STARTF_USESTDHANDLES = 0x00000100;
        
        String szCmdline = cmd;

        PROCESS_INFORMATION processInformation = new PROCESS_INFORMATION();
        STARTUPINFO startupInfo = new STARTUPINFO();
        startupInfo.cb = new DWORD(processInformation.size());
        startupInfo.hStdError = childStdOutWrite.getValue();
        startupInfo.hStdOutput = childStdOutWrite.getValue();
        startupInfo.hStdInput = childStdInRead.getValue();
        startupInfo.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
 
        // Create the child process. 
        HANDLE hToken = null;
        MyWtsapi32 mw = MyWtsapi32.INSTANCE;
        mw.WTSQueryUserToken(Kernel32Ext.INSTANCE.WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId(), hToken) ;

      //be sure that the handle is correct ! (can be the issue)
      if (hToken == null) logger.info("Token error.");
        if (!Advapi32.INSTANCE.CreateProcessAsUser(
                hToken, 
                szCmdline, 
                null, 
                null, 
                null,
                true, 
                32, 
                null, 
                null, 
                startupInfo, 
                processInformation)){
           // System.err.println(Advapi32.INSTANCE.GetLastError());
            logger.error("Cannot create process as User ");
            logger.error("error code "+Native.getLastError());
        }
```

**MyWtsApi32.java**

```
public interface MyWtsapi32 extends Wtsapi32 {
      // Your own instance to access your functions
     MyWtsapi32 INSTANCE =  Native.load("Wtsapi32", MyWtsapi32.class, W32APIOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);
    
    // From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-messagebox
    int MB_OK = 0; 

    // The function to send the message
      boolean WTSSendMessageW(HANDLE hServer, int SessionId,
        LPWSTR pTitle, int TitleLength,
        LPWSTR pMessage, int MessageLength,
        int Style, int Timeout, IntByReference pResponse, boolean bWait);
      
      boolean WTSQueryUserToken(long SessionId,HANDLE hServer);
}
```

**Kernel32Ext.java**

```
public interface Kernel32Ext extends Kernel32{
    Kernel32Ext INSTANCE = Native.load("Kernel32",Kernel32Ext.class,W32APIOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);
    
    int WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your JNA function mappings don't work, the first debugging step should be to check your function mappings.

`WTSQueryUserToken` is defined as:

```
BOOL WTSQueryUserToken(
    ULONG SessionId,
    PHANDLE phToken
);
```

The Windows type `ULONG` is [an unsigned 32-bit integer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types); it should be mapped as `int`, not `long`.

`PHANDLE` is a pointer to a `HANDLE`, not the handle itself.  The correct JNA mapping is `HANDLEByReference`.

So your interface function mapping should be:

```java
boolean WTSQueryUserToken(int SessionId, HANDLEByReference hServer);
```

And your code to call it should be:

```java
HANDLEByReference phToken = new HANDLEByReference();
MyWtsapi32 mw = MyWtsapi32.INSTANCE;
// you should probably check the return value here
// on failure throw LastErrorException
mw.WTSQueryUserToken(Kernel32Ext.INSTANCE.WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId(), phToken);

// Extract the HANDLE for use in later code
HANDLE hToken = phToken.getValue();
```

Comment: This is resolved now, HANDLEByReference was the issue. Cmd "C:\Windows\notepad.exe" is running and opening a notepad window. But the same thing is not working when command passed to run a .jar file. For example : "java -jar C:\\MyApp.jar" . getLastError() is giving 123 code, that means INVALID_PATH . Don't know why. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: @Mr.code is Java on your path?  Try the full path to the JRE binary.

Comment: Yes Java is on my path, works fine if I run same command through cmd line. I have also tried giving full path to java in the command but not working. If I make the app executable jar and give command "C:\\MyApp.jar", its giving code 193 that means "ERROR_BAD_EXE_FORMAT" . Does this means we can only run exe files?

Comment: @Mr.code try adding "CMD /C" before the java command, to "wrap" it in a command shell.